# Remove double quotes if delimiter value is not present in data

Tags: csv, perl, awk, sed

An input file is given, each line of which contains quotes for each column and carriage return/ new line character.

- If the line contains new lines it has be appended with in the same
  line which is inside the quotes i.e for example line 1
- Removing of double quotes for each column if the delimiter(,) is
  not present.
- Removing of Carriage Return characters i.e(^M)

To exemplify, given the following input file

```
"name","address","age"^M
"ram","abcd,^M
def","10"^M
"abhi","xyz","25"^M
"ad","ram,John","35"^M
```

I would like to obtain the following output by means of a sed/perl/awk script/oneliner.

```
name,address,age
ram,"abcd,def",10
abhi,xyz,25
ad,"ram,John",35
```

Solutions which i have tired it so far
For appending with previous line

```
sed '/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/{N;s/\n//}' sample.txt
```

for replacing control-m characters

```
perl -pne 's/\\r//g' sample.txt
```

But i didn't achieve final output what i required below

Comment: To get rid of `^M` you can do `dos2unix sample.txt`

Comment: This is CSV format data, you probably DON'T want to get rid of the quotes. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Tell us what you're _REALLY_ trying to accomplish, i.e. why you think you need to remove the quotes.

Comment: `cat yourfile | dos2unix | tr -d '"'`

Comment: David tr with removing double quotes it removes all quotes ?

Comment: @david : I want to achieve the output what is shown above. I want to remove quotes where the delimiter value is not present in the data

Comment: I got you, sorry, my quick look looked like you wanted to remove all double-quotes.

Comment: Are you SURE there's `^M`s (`\r`s) inside the quoted fields? If this were a file exported from Excel, for example, then there'd be `\r\n` at the end of each record but inside the quoted fields it'd only be `\n` for the newline, not `\r\n`. In any case, to handle it with awk see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/[^"]$/{N;s/\n//;ba};s/"\([^",]*\)"/\1/g' file
```

The solution is in two parts:

1. Join broken lines to make whole ones.
2. Remove double quotes surrounding fields that do not contain commas.

If the current line does not end with double quotes, append the next line, remove the newline and repeat. Otherwise: remove double quotes surrounding fields that do not contain double quotes or commas.

N.B. Supposes that fields do not contain quoted double quotes. If that is the case, the condition for the first step would need to be amended and double quotes within fields would need to catered for.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. If i am not sure how many columns come in future. in that case the solution provided by you it wont be feasible.

Comment: @user1485267 I over thought the problem, see amended simplified solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use a library to parse CSV files.  Apart from always wanting to use a library for that here you also have very specific reasons, with embedded newlines and delimiters.

In Perl a good library is [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) (which wraps `Text::CSV_XS` if installed).  A basic example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file.csv\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 }); 

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
    s/\n+//g for @$row; 
    $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Comments

- The `binary` option in the constructor is what handles newlines embedded in data
- Once a line is read into the array reference `$row` I remove newlines in each field with a simplistic regex. By all means please improve this as/if needed
- The pruning of `$row` works as follows.  In a `foreach` loop each element is really aliased by the loop variable, so if that gets changed the array changes. I used default where elements are aliased by `$_`, which the regex changes so `$row` changes.

  I like this compact shortcut because it has such a distinct look that I can tell from across the room that an array is being changed in place; so I consider it a sort-of-an-idiom. But if it is in fact confusing please by all means write out a full and proper loop
- The processed output is printed to `STDOUT`. Or, open an output file and pass that filehandle to `say` (or to `print` in older module versions) so the output goes directly to that file

The above prints, for the sample input provided in the question

```
name,address,age
ram,"abcd,def",10
abhi,xyz,25
ad,"ram,John",35
```

Answer (score 2):

`FPAT` is the way to go using `gnu awk`, it handles comma separated files.

1. remove ^m
2. clean lines
3. remove qutes

.

```
dos2unix sample.txt  

awk '{printf "%s"(/,$/?"":"\n"),$0}' sample.txt > tmp && mv tmp sample.txt
"name","address","age"
"ram","abcd,def","10"
"abhi","xyz","25"
"ad","ram,John","35"


awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!~",") $i=substr($i,2,length($i)-2)}1' sample.txt
name,address,age
ram,"abcd,def",10
abhi,xyz,25
ad,"ram,John",35
```

All in one go:

```
dos2unix sample.txt && awk '{printf "%s"(/,$/?"":"\n"),$0}' sample.txt | awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!~",") $i=substr($i,2,length($i)-2)}1'
```

Normally you set Filed Separator `FS or F` to tell how filed are separated.  `FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`  FPAT tells how the filed looks like using a regex.  This regex is complicated and often used with CSV.

- `(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` loop through on by one field on the line.
- `if($i!~",")` if it does not contain comma, then
- `$i=substr($i,2,length($i)-2)` remove first and last character, the `"`

If a field for some reason do not contain `"`, this is more robust:

```
awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!~",") {n=split($i,a,"\"");$i=(n>1?a[2]:$i)}}1' file
```

It will not do any thing to a field not contains double quote.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Can you explain me the last pattern which you have applied. awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!~",") $i=substr($i,2,length($i)-2)}1' sample.txt

Comment: @user1485267 added some more info

Comment: Thanks for the info. But with third function it doesn't work i got same ouptut what i achived in second step

Comment: Currently awk version which i am trying is GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: Jotne - the OP has a newline within a quoted field, you can't handle that with just FPAT. @user1485267 that version of gawk is 10 years out of date (it was released in 2009), we're now on gawk 5.0.1 - you should update your version as you're missing a TON of great functionality (including FPAT) and some bug fixes, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History for the list of features added per release and https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/ for the release dates.

Comment: @EdMorton That is why I added two awk :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't get that the first script was trying to combine lines. Got it, thx.

Comment: @Jotne : Sorry i cannot update the version. I have to try with the current version itself whatever the possibilities are there

Comment: @user1485267 sounds that you are on an outdated system and should upgrade all.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, please try the following:

```
perl -e '
while (<>) {
    s/\r$//;      # remove trailing CR code
    $str .= $_;
}

while ($str =~ /("(("")|[^"])*"\n?)|((^|(?<=,))[^,]*((?=,)|\n))/g) {
    $_ = $&;
    if (/,/) {    # the element contains ","
        s/\n//g;  # then remove newline(s) if any
    } else {      # otherwise remove surrounding double quotes
        s/^"//s; s/"$//s;
    }
    push(@ary, $_);

    if (/\n$/) {  # newline terminates the element
        print join(",", @ary);
        @ary = ();
    }
}' sample.txt
```

Output:

```
name,address,age
ram,"abcd,def",10
abhi,xyz,25
ad,"ram,John",35
```